# Proving $\frac{L_n(x)^2}{4}-\left(\frac{x^2}{4}+1\right) \cdot F_n(x)^2=(-1)^n$, where $L_n(x)$ and $F_n(x)$ are the Lucas and Fibonacci polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, reference-request, pell-type-equations

Recently, I found the following identity:

> $$\frac{L_n(x)^2}{4}-\left(\frac{x^2}{4}+1\right) \cdot F_n(x)^2=(-1)^n $$
> where $L_n(x)$ denotes the [Lucas polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_polynomials#Examples) and $F_n(x)$ denotes the [Fibonacci polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_polynomials#Examples).

The SageMath cell that demonstrates this identity can be found [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1jtEKgzAMRd_9ksQqNmXsJcuvCNtQVqwlOGXC2L-vUreHwd4uh5NDohy5CMv1fIcR5alWHCvJyiGNx82HDsJJxkplLZWMWk6K0uYoB2OQp25epgiKLy56f_lk7KYQD9_M8Dcz_GZ8D1HEVjr5OANhlQHtoE4kL8ifR2wctq6GtXXNwRCWsH0SMUFE5GK302Ebkd-D9Uhu&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

Is this identity already known? If it is could you provide a reference?

Comment: An underappreciated method for proving identities like this is to use the Binet type closed form expressing Fibonacci and Lucas as sums of powers of functions $a(x)$ and $b(x)$. See for example https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.01855.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is well known that $(-1)^n=F_{n+1}F_{n-1}-F_n^2$ and so your identity is equivalent to
$$\left (\frac{L_n-xF_n}{2}\right )\left (\frac{L_n+xF_n}{2}\right )=F_{n+1}F_{n-1},$$
but Lucas sequence is such that $F_{n+m}=\frac{F_nL_m+F_mL_n}{2}$ so if $m=1$ you have $F_{n+1}=\frac{F_nL_1+L_nF_1}{2}=\frac{L_n+xF_n}{2}$ And analogously doing $F_{n+1}-xF_n=F_{n-1}$ your identity holds.